# How to associate a MFC DC with QPrinter?

Tags: qt, printing, mfc, gdi, qprinter

I was just wondering if it is possible to use my existing MFC created DC to associate with a `QPrinter` so that it directly uses the existing DC rather creates its own with `QPrintDialog`?

Does `QPrinter` make use of Qt's backingstore as `QWidget` does, i.e., does it create an off-screen image before printing?

Answer (score 0):

First thing:
QPrintDialog has nothing to do with your question.
You can set-up a QPrinter without using QPrintDialog.

Anyway: You paint into a QPainter where QPrinter is "only" the printing device. Printing only starts when you end the QPainter. So there is a backing store when using QPrinter.

You can't convert a DC to a QPainter so QPrinter can't do anything with a DC. The closest thing would be to get a Bitmap from the DC and print it to a fresh QPainter.